# Eclipse Java Remote Project won't build and run

Tags: java, eclipse-rse

I have spent 6h+ and finally I've decided to seek the community's help.

I have a Java project on a remote SSH cluster and I have imported it into eclipse using RSE (Remote System Explorer). This project used to be a local project and has many libraries/dependencies. I have configured all of them and all of the paths are accessible on the remote cluster.

I want to run it on the remote cluster using SSH as well (via Eclipse External Tools). I have configured EVERYTHING and have even successfully ran another project. However, right now the problem is that Eclipse does not create even a SINGLE .class file on the remote server!!!

The project does not have any errors (if I just copy its `bin` folder from my computer to the remote cluster it works) but, since Eclipse does not produce a single .class file, there is nothing to run in its `bin` folder on the remote cluster.
It's also worth mentioning that for some reason that I don't understand, there is a red x on the projects name in Project Exlorer (indicating error) but there is no such thing on any of the source codes/packages in this project.
The "Build Automatically" option is active and cleaning and building it manually won't work either.

Any help is hugely appreciated as I am really desperate and need to get this thing working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the 'problems' view / 'Errors' view to see what the actual problem is

Comment: Also "Markers" view is usually very helpful.

Comment: @Lavanya Yes first it was complaining about some text files (something about they already exist) but now it's saying something that doesn't make any sense: the file ****.java could not be read! This file exists and also it can be opened in Eclipse...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks for the reply. What is that? I have no idea what this is :(

Comment: @m2x it is a view containing errors, warnings, todos etc. very handy... It can be opened if not shown (is by default in eclipse JEE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to solve this problem and the only thing I could think of was a bug within Eclipse. It seems that because of slow transfer rates to/from cluster, some of the files could not be built as they were partly fetched/stored. I ended up writing a shell script that would transfer the files to the remote cluster and compiled and ran it on there.

If anyone has a better suggestion, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this solution worked for me:
In my java context.xml file in the META-INF folder (local project context), I added path="/myProjectName" and it started building automatically.

```
<Context path="/jvals" antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
<Resource name="jdbc/jvals"....
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem in another way ;
go to the remote project in linux ;

cd youRemoteProject/build/classes
if your jars is in xxx\lib\a.jar, b.jar

java -cp ".;xxx\lib*" package.package.className

( you must using Java 6 or later, classpath wildcards are a part of the JVM )